# GeoJson File for INDIA

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson

I am trying to make a map in D3 like this, but for INDIA :

```
http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312
```

Here, they have json file for the us-states as on this location **(uStates.js)** :

```
https://gist.github.com/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312
```

Now, I am unable to get json file in this format for states of India. I have few shapes file and other geojson files, but none matches the data like this.

Can anyone let me know if they know of how can i make a similar map for INDIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created [indiaState.js](https://gist.github.com/dixitchoksi/6a55808ecfa80a9c707309268d2af00c) file, please check this will definitely help you.

Comment: @sahil remitly2 please check

Comment: thanks for sharing, but...why just a link-only answer? please, be aware, it would be great and useful to hear from you also an explanation about the map file creation process..

Comment: @deblocker I also face this same problem and I search a lot but nothing got, so I created my own JSON file for India map and share to the public so people can easily get the answer.